# How to write component in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to know how can I write a component in codeigniter
I have worked with symfony1.4 and there there is something include_component("name",dataarray()) that we can load a component ( it's actually an action ).

I already know that we have $this->load->view('admin/template/login') for loading a view, But I want to know is there any way to call an action like this?

this->load(news/list,array('date'=>xxx-xx-xx))

thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

you can this through the use of libraries, helpers or plugins.

an example of using a library class in `application/library` called `LoadNews.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class LoadNews {

  public function showList($date_array) {
    // do stuff with date array
  }
}

/* End of file LoadNews.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/LoadNews.php */
```

then in your controller, you call

```
$this->load->library('LoadNews');
$this->loadnews->showList(array('date'=>'2014-12-19'));
```

Comment: That's a good Idea but can I render a view in library? because I symfony1.4 a component is an action actually that when you call it, it preaper the proper data and then call it's action. but if I use libraries in here, is it possible to call a view in library? if so, is it a best practice?

Comment: Yes I too love the component based structure of frameworks like Symfony or Anuglar. Have you got this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this from CI 3.
In your Controller or View just call $this->load->view(view, data);
Example:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') or die('No direct script allowed');

    class PageController extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $data = [
                'names' => ['john', 'doe'],
                'ages' => ['24', '30']
            ];
            $this->load->view('index', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

And in your view you can access 'names' and 'ages' as `$names` and `$ages` respectively.

You can do this in your view:

```
<?php 
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($names);
        print_r($ages);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The result:

```
Array (
    [0] => john
    [1] => doe
)
Array (
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 30
)
```